# pythonic way to set the elements of a loop to a constant based on a condition

Tags: python

Is it possible to write a nice, Pythonic one-liner for something where you have to loop through the elements of a list and set them to some constant based on a condition?

Here is what my current implementation looks like:

```
var = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(var)):
    var[i] = 0 if var[i] <= 0 else var[i]
```

I understand that you could just use a normal if-statement inside of the for-loop as well, but I'm rather unfamiliar with all that Python has to offer and am looking for something a bit nicer.

NOTE: I want to modify the original array, not create a new one (e.g. there should be some (though perhaps very slight) overhead added when creating a new list via list comprehension as opposed to modifying the original array)

Comment: You could use a list comprehension.

Comment: Generally, you never want to loop over `range(len(var))` anyway.

Comment: Regarding all the answers here... [Fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: Do you need to update the list in-place or is creating a new list ok ?

Comment: I want to update the list. Creating a new one is a rather trivial one-line list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) you can use [index masks](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
var = numpy.array([...])
var[var < 0] = 0
```

Comment: Perfect and very clean. Though it uses an external library `numpy` that doesn't matter to me since `numpy` is so highly optimized.

Answer (score 4):

You can do :

```
var = [max(i,0) for i in var]
```

Comment: Tbh I'll admit I didn't think of doing a list comprehension that way (I would have used a more verbose if-statement). But also not what I was asking for

Comment: @J-Win imo this is the best answer, if you want to apply another function to `i` then just define that function using `def` and apply list comprehension to that function.

Comment: I don't need to create another list. Again, I am trying to avoid that over head. Therefore, in my opinion, the answer I selected above is the best answer

Comment: The answer you selected is very clean and doesn't create a new list, but a new numpy array... I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension and check each element:

```
var = [1,2,-3,4]
var = [(i if i > 0 else 0) for i in var]

print(var) # [1, 2, 0, 4]
```

Just for fun I've timed all the current answers that do not rely on third party libraries:

```
import timeit

print( timeit.timeit( "[(i if i > 0 else 0) for i in var]", setup="var = [1,2,-3,4]", number=1000000 ) )
# 0.6322694380378722
print( timeit.timeit( "[0 if item < 0 else item for item in var]", setup="var = [1,2,-3,4]", number=1000000 ) )
# 0.6328021787321703
print( timeit.timeit( "[max(i,0) for i in var]", setup="var = [1,2,-3,4]", number=1000000 ) )
# 1.4293624092194928
```

Comment: Benchmarking the first vs. the second method is not really meaningful because it just inverts the check ("greater than" vs. "less than"). Also you should include the benchmarks for `numpy`, admittedly it is not part of the standard library, but it is much faster than all the other methods. And OSX even ships with `numpy` installed.

Comment: @a_guest You're right that the first and the second are basically the same. However, I can not benchmark numpy, as I do not have it installed.

Comment: Thanks for going through the trouble of adding timing benchmarks, but this was also not what I wanted. Though not explicitly stated, the question does state that I desire to *set* the elements of the list

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in multiple ways, and this is one of them:

`var = [0 if item < 0 else item for item in var]`

Comment: Yes, but I believe that list comprehensions create an entire new list correct? I just wanted to set the elements of the existing array to avoid such overhead

Comment: @J-Win it will create this list and remove the old instance of it. It's like faking the in-place setting of the elements.

Comment: Yes, but that isn't the point. Under the hood, there is still the (though minor) overhead of creating a new array